# How do I add the .cs output to the project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

I'm using VS 2010 and a T4 template to generate some partial classes with some routines into a .cs file. The code looks great but the project can't see the file, I can't hightlight it and include it in the project.

The generated partial class has this in it:

```
public partial class ContactAddresses
{ 
    public void hithere() {}
}
```

but when I instantiate an object of that type it doesn't see the method.

What am I missing?

Comment: What kind of T4 template is it? A *Text Template* (compiletime) or a *Deferred Text Template* (runtime)?

Comment: Maybe the namespaces for the various parts of the partial class are different (thuis they are separate classes)?

Comment: This soundl like your solution knows nothing about generated file. Maybe you should add generated file to your solution. Check the <project name>.csproj file.

Comment: Its a '.tt' file. The namespaces look good. How do I manually add a file to the project? Thanks!

Comment: To manually add file to project, click the icon which says "Show all files" in the solution explorer and then right click the file which you need to add, then select "Include" this file. Example: http://socialsp.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/showall.jpg

Comment: When I use the context menu on the .cs file I don't get the 'include in project', I thought you might have meant that. Perhaps I can back up and ask the question in a different way: Should .cs files that are generated from .tt automatically be included in the build? If not, what steps need to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the files to be added to another folder, you will need to do some extra stuff to add that file in the project. One good option is to use t4toolbox [here](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/03/t4-toolbox-generating-files-in-different-folders-and-projects/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm not moving them, just trying to get them to be part of the build so I can reference them. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. If I add a .tt file that generates a .cs file what do I have to do to have that included in the build?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is that the .cs files generated by the .tt template are being included in the build automatically. I created an empty class in the tt file with a constructor, saw that it was generated and was able to new it.

The bug was that I was trying to add EntityFramework classes but the template code picked up the database names, the 's' at the end meant it was a different class.

thank you everyone for your response.